# Spring boot JPA repository query error not reload data to entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is my controller

```
@Controller
public class RouteReportController {
    
    @Autowired ReportService reportService;

    @GetMapping("/data")
    public void getDataReport (){

        String []arrayData = {"BSD","AIM","GAF","MIS","OPR","ENG"};

        for (int i=0;i<arrayData.length;i++) {
            List<Report> dataReport = reportRepository.lstReportAbnormal(arrayData[i],"ALL","01-Mar-2024","21-Mar-2024","VDPP");
            System.out.println("===========***=============");
            System.out.println("Data Index :"+i+" PoDep : "+arrayData[i] + " Data Rep: "+dataReport.get(0).getDepartment());
            
        }



    }

}
```

This is my Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Report{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "Em_id")
    private String emId;
    
    @Column(name = "Em_Name")
    private String emName;
    
    ..../

Getter and Setter



    }
```

```
@Repository
public interface ReportRepository extends JpaRepository<Report, Long>{
    
    @Query(value = "{call [sp_hr_load_abnormal_mail](:Depart,:Section,:StartDate,:ToDate,:WorkSite)}",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Report>lstReportAbnormal
    (   @Param("Depart") String Depart,
        @Param("Section") String Section,
        @Param("StartDate") String StartDate,
        @Param("ToDate") String ToDate,
        @Param("WorkSite") String WorkSite
    );
}
```

This is data sysout

```
===========***=============
Data Index :0 PoDep : BSD Data Rep: BSD 
===========***=============
Data Index :1 PoDep : AIM Data Rep: BSD
===========***=============
Data Index :2 PoDep : GAF Data Rep: BSD 
===========***=============
Data Index :3 PoDep : MIS Data Rep: BSD
```

Data I need when loop by loop form controller data like that I mention
Data Index : Data index of loop

```
===========***=============
Data Index :0 PoDep : BSD Data Rep: BSD 
===========***=============
Data Index :1 PoDep : AIM Data Rep: AIM 
===========***=============
Data Index :2 PoDep : GAF Data Rep: GAF 
===========***=============
Data Index :3 PoDep : MIS Data Rep: MIS
```

Data that I want to reponse like this

One loop one list of paramater and after that new loop new  data reponse

Sorry for my new user for ask Spring boots

Comment: It seems you are calling a stored procedure. Since you don't show any code for that, there is no way to tell, why it returns the data you are seeing.

I would at least display all the data returned, i.e. the full list, not just data from one row.